# How do you ask a question in comments when you don't have enough reputation to do so?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, questions

Here has been my recent experience:
 I was attempting to improve the community of stack exchange as its the first resource I usually hit when searching for a programming problem. Usually the questions I responded on were unclear or had multiple questions.

Problem:
  I could not ask questions in comments because my REP was not 50.
  I asked follow up questions posted in the WRONG area... as an ANSWER! 
  (Even though I could not post them in the right area... catch 22).
  I ended up with more down votes and less reputation after contributing.

The questions I asked caused the OPs to provide more information which led to the correct answer eventually.  I don't care about REP; I was interested in helping an OP with a similar problem I had encountered and figured 'documentation' would help.

My main contribution would be to ask piercing questions into the nature of the persons problem, which cause them to think and eventually discover either more information or even the solution to the problem.

I couldn't post questions in comments because my rep was to low... I couldn't get up voted for asking good follow up questions in the comments because I could not post there.

This is the definition of a catch 22.

The REP isn't important, the ability contribute is.   I ended up deleting all these posts because of the bad experience Stack Exchange has left me with.

Why is there a 50 min REP barrier for comments?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here - **Upvotes in comments have no effect on your rep** - asking good questions (not comments) and providing good answers (again, not in comments) provides rep.

Comment: So - essentially, it's to stop spam. I don't understand how putting this barrier up prevents spam when the potential spammer can post the same material as an "answer." It's a busywork-goldmine for those that concern themselves with tagging genuine 'please clarify' "answers" as 'not an answer.' Much better in my view to allow these comments  - but include them in the "First Posts" review queue.

Comment: I was mistaken on the understanding of how reputation works on comments. @Chris
Also, I agree Magoo. This barrier to entry stops me from asking 'Please Clarification Questions'.  Not sure how this stops spam.  Perhaps a CAPTHA to post comments?

Answer (score 13):

Rather than give you the usual explanations about how we need a small barrier to entry for people who would otherwise spam the site, let me simply point out that *Stack Overflow is not a social network.*

The primary goal of Stack Overflow is to *ask questions and get answers.*  The sole purpose of comments is to support that activity by providing a means to clarify the question asked; if the question you're trying to answer is unclear or incomplete, but you don't have enough reputation to post comments yet, then just find another question that is clearer to answer.

Once you earn 50 reputation points (which can easily be done with a couple of well-placed answers on questions), you will gain the ability to ask those clarifying questions in comments.