# Is it OK to use an "answer" to comment if you lack the reputation to comment?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments, low-quality-posts, new-users

The Low Quality Posts queue has as one of the reasons to delete an "answer" is that it should instead have been posted as a comment.

Commenting is a privilege. I've been happily voting to delete comments-as-answers from low reputation users. However, I saw one example where another user had commented on the pseudo-answer that it was *perfectly OK* to post comments as answers if you did not have the reputation to post a comment.

Is it really OK? I think not, but clearly someone does. Who is correct?

Comment: No. You are correct. An answer is supposed to be an answer. Not a comment. No clue where that idea came from.

Comment: High chances that someone else will do the comment soon or later anyway if it's worth it.

Comment: At least one other person seems to agree with me:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252224/545127

Comment: Official policy is that it is not OK:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: Might want to go find that user and point him/her there... Encouraging comments-as-answers is not a good idea.

Comment: See also:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258530/how-to-handle-answers-that-should-be-comments-but-the-answerer-doesnt-have-enou

Comment: I vaguely remember something on meta about moderators migrating comment style answers of low rep users to comments. Sometimes a user is clearly trying to be helpful and just needs some more information but they don't have the comment privilege and it's times like those that I feel that being more hardline on the rules is counter productive. The chat privilege is probably the only other one that I find can be overly limiting too.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR That's definitely still possible, but if memory serves the mods don't really like to use that ability. I can't tell you the reason behind it, although I could guess that it's because it'd just encourage more comments-as-answers...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## No

It is not ok to post comments as answers. If a user doesn't have enough reputation to post a comment, **then they need to earn it**, by having 10 upvotes on good questions, 5 upvotes on good answers, or making 25 good suggested edits.

**No exceptions**.

Comment: Or just two accepted answers that have been upvoted once, each. =)

Comment: Ya mean 5 answer upvotes or 10 question upvotes?

Answer (score -13):

#### No, but I don't blame people for doing so

I personally have wanted to contribute to SO many times.

More often than not, however, what I have to contribute *should* be a comment on an existing answer. For example, someone else's answer is largely correct, but one assumption will cause serious consequences in some cases - I could point this out, but it certainly isn't a different answer.

I do not have enough reputation to comment.

So I don't contribute. Instead I fret over the fact that I could have saved someone if not for the reputation barrier.

Should I post an answer? After all, my contribution is worthwhile - the reputation barrier wasn't meant for me. I'm special, dammit!

Comment: If you want to comment, then earn the 50 rep to be able to do so, don't complain about the consequences of intentionally violating the rules.

Comment: Wow, harsh response. Who's complaining about the consequences? And who's intentionally violating the rules? Certainly not me. I was merely (tongue in cheek) pointing out that some people genuinely want to help others and do what they think is right. The design of the site pushes people toward this action, especially if they haven't read the small print. The reputation barrier excludes potentially useful insights and contributions. Why should newcomers "earn" the right to help others - it is a gift given, not a privilege. The way newcomers are treated here - just for trying to help - is toxic.

Comment: Um...*you* are complaining about the consequences...that's...what this answer is doing.  *You*re the one trying to excuse violating the rules, even though you know they're there.  That people are trying to help doesn't change the fact that they *aren't*, and there's an *appropriate* way to do what they're trying to do.  The fact barrier has been shown to be a necessary one to keep out harmful content.  Intentionally violating rules and insulting people for enforcing them - is toxic.

Comment: I think there has been some serious miscommunication here. I do not advocate violating the rules. I do not violate the rules. The fact that people are unknowingly violating the rules has no bearing on whether or not they can help or whether or not they should be treated with respect.
Of course there needs to be a barrier against harmful and superfluos content. Intentionally violating rules and insulting anyone for any reason is a terrible thing to do. I am not insulting anyone. But you, sir, are insulting me, and in a particularly nasty fashion. It is totally uncalled for.

Comment: People are treated respectfully when they violate this rule.  The invalid post is deleted and an explanation given.  Your answer *is* advocating violating the rules.  You're saying that you're special and the rule doesn't exist exist for you so you should be able to violate it without consequence, so you're advocating intentionally violating the rules.  You're calling people toxic for having the gall to enforce their own rules, and not treating you like a special snowflake that should be above the rules.  I'm not insulting you, I'm explaining to you how the site works.

Comment: So, what is your intent with this answer? How does this answer the question? It sounds like you're just complaining that you can't comment, which is not a good answer.

Comment: Ok, this is pointless. You are now outright lying. Every single thing you just claimed I said or think - I didn't, and I don't.
I am not advocating violating the rules. I am not special (I assume you didn't notice my sarcasm or imitation to make a point). The rule clearly exists for everyone, as it should. People should not violate it, violations should not be permitted. I am not advocating intentional violation of the rules. Never did, never have, never would. I am not calling people toxic for enforcing rules. You accuse me of almost the exact opposite of my position for no reason.

Comment: The intent with the answer was to add that, whilst it is not OK, newcomers should be treated with an ounce of patience and not insulted for their efforts, if their intentions were positive. As opposed to treating them how they tend to be - this response to my answer being a perfect example. In fact, I personally had never had an issue before now, but this experience really doesn't make me want to make an effort to contribute.

Comment: Commenting is nice - but not mandatory. The site is really content-oriented and thus actually invites you to post a better answer yourself. It may take some effort to really make your answer stand out and perhaps sometimes you really cannot, but if you manage to do that then you really played towards the ultimate goal of the site; to collect good questions with the best answers. At this point people can break however because they conjure up all kinds of personal honor-driven rules about what is "correct" or not. Keep in mind: Stack Overflow likes really good answers. Got one? Provide it.

Comment: (and that is re: *More often than not, however, what I have to contribute should be a comment on an existing answer.*)