# Is it OK to write too detailed comment as Answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, not-an-answer

While I agree with the **NO** answer for

[Is it OK to use an “answer” to comment if you lack the reputation to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265784/2521214)

I sometimes have the need to specify some things that needs much more details which will not fit into 1/2 or 3 comment sometimes even with **images** or some piece of **formatted code** especially for Questions asked by people not realizing the extend of information lacking in the original post of theirs.

**I usually handle those like this:**

Adding detailed comment as an Answer with starting text like "This is not an answer!". Following by the things I need to clear ... This is example of such comment of mine:

[3D : keep horizon drawn on screen at the same height regardless camera's zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28231746/2521214)

As you can see the question got answered and accepted (I am totally OK with it). My question is:

**Q1. Is it OK to post such comments as "Answers"?**

**Q2. Shall I left it as is (to help others see the rest of info) or delete it after:**

- Question got Accepted answer (keeping in mind that there is no notification that question got accepted answer)
- Requested info is added to OP

If the OP response and no Valid Answers present I usually convert such posts to real answers.

Comment: Leaving aside your primary question here - if you need to post a [6-part commentary with diagrams](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28231746/1709587) to explain to the question author what details their question needs adding to make it answerable and to provide broad overviews of approaches to the different possibilities, doesn't that suggest that the question needs closing as either "Unclear what you're asking" or "Too broad"? I see no close votes on it right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't post answers that aren't answers.

If you need so much additional information from the OP that you can't fit what you need in a comment, then flag the question as unclear and/or ask the OP to go to a chat room to discuss it.

If the post actually does work as an answer, you can just post it as an answer and leave out the parts meant to ask the OP for additional info.

You're probably not worried about rep at this point but what you're currently doing could prevent posts that need to be closed and deleted from being removed from the site.

Comment: Answers don't prevent closure. Upvoted answers do block the automatic deletion by the roomba.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - The OP's example non-answer answer post has two up votes.