# User Posts Non-Answer but Can't Comment

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I was going through the Late Answer queue when I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362819/how-to-put-and-download-the-content-of-a-div-in-html-into-pdf-file-using-js/33452277#33452277) non-answer posted as an answer.

I down-voted it because it *isn't* an answer and is asking for more information (which is exactly what comments are for). I was going to leave a comment telling the poster to leave a comment next time (s)he does something like this, but (s)he doesn't have enough reputation to leave comments.

I know that I could just say "wait until you have more rep then comment" but by then the question might already be answered and this isn't the first time this has happened.

Is there a standard/recommended procedure to follow for this kind of situation?

**EDIT** just to clarify:

This isn't strictly about flagging the question, I'm aware of the not-an-answer flag, but what about the user? Do I just tell them that they just have to deal with the fact that they can't comment yet and therefore can't properly answer the question? Seems a little cold and unhelpful.

Comment: There's a flag for this situation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See my edit. Am I seriously just supposed to tell them that they just have to deal with the fact that they can't comment yet?

Comment: Yes, just leave an explanatory comment.

Comment: You can explain that this rule exists because if it didn't we'd have spammers invading comments. You can also point out about suggested edits, which can help you go up to 50 rep easily :). Until they reach that, they have to do as we all did : answer questions that are clear enough so don't need commenting on :)

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174

Comment: *"Do I just tell them that they just have to deal with the fact that they can't comment yet"* - yes, pretty much!

Comment: I would suggest not telling new users that they can get enough rep to post comments if they suggest a bunch of edits unless you also tell them that tiny, trivial edits are discouraged and they should try to make the post significantly better when they edit, correcting all problems that they observe

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr -  **No** , the user should not be encouraged to find a loophole for the rule.

There will always be a few corner cases, where maybe the rule doesn't make sense in *that* specific case (I think I'd raise my hand - lately I've been going up and down over 50 points ). But the reason for the 50-point threshold is to prevent all the spammers. You have to punish a few people for the good of everyone, is the case here. But yeah, you can easily attain 50 points. It is just 25 suggested edits, which anyone can quickly attain.

So, in the end - the 50 point comment threshold is not a *big* barrier. It is more of annoyance to *some*, but we can live with it. Some people go around it and post comments as answers, but we have to block that. Perhaps a mod can convert it to  a comment if it is a good comment-worthy . Otherwise, notify them that this isn't the rules.

[Is it OK to use an "answer" to comment if you lack the reputation to comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265783/is-it-ok-to-use-an-answer-to-comment-if-you-lack-the-reputation-to-comment)