# How to inform users why their answer was recommended for deletion?

Tags: support

I just started reviewing posts, and twice I wanted to be able to tell something to the user beyond the options offered:

- Once was a user posting an a comment as an answer, and then commenting on their own answer that they were doing this because they didn't have enough reputation. I of course put the reason "this is a comment, not an answer" but being able to give the user [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265783/is-it-ok-to-use-an-answer-to-comment-if-you-lack-the-reputation-to-comment) as additional information would have been great.
- The other time is when the user made a post that started with "I want everyone who read this question to know ..." with some things after. It could have been valid (at least partly) if the rest of the post answered the problem, so I opened the question in full to look into more detail. And then I saw that it was his second answer on the question and was actually commenting on the content of his first answer. There was no option "should be an edit to the first post", so I just put no reason when recommending for deletion.

Sometimes when the reason doesn't fit perfectly with the options, it'd be nice to actually be able to input why in plain text, for the user to see and understand. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: _"Is there any way to do this?"_ Go back there after reviewing (save the link), and write a comment as you like.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I thought about that, but if the post is going to be deleted (which is presumably going to be quick) then the user won't be able to see the comment

Comment: I take it you are in the low quality post queue.  If you are you can comment directly on the answer while in the queue and when done you can pick the no comment option since you manually commented.

Comment: @coyotte508 Users can see their deleted posts, as well as +10k rep users can.

Comment: Alright, thanks to you both.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But notifications on deleted posts are also deleted, so you will likely never find out about the comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just click "*add comment*" on the answer, write what you want, and then select "*no comment needed*" when recommending deletion.

The user will get an inbox notification for that comment - although not if they don't check their inbox before the answer is deleted.

Comment: `As far as I understand, the user will still get an inbox notification for that comment, even if the answer is subsequently deleted. (Not 100% sure about this though.)`  That's wrong.  They will not.

Comment: Edited my answer - that kinda seems a bit counterintuitive. Do you know of any feature request or discussion asking to change that behaviour though ?

Comment: Your answer is still wrong.  Comments added by the queue result in a notification even if the answer is deleted.  I wouldn't expect there to be any reason to show notifications for normal comments posted on answers that have since been deleted.  I expect it's probably been proposed before, but I wouldn't expect it to be accepted.

Comment: At least, the user will still be able to see their deleted post, so if they check on it and see it's deleted they'll still have the explanation.