# How do I ask clarifying questions without 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious what standard procedure is for getting clarification for a question asked when I don't have 50 reputation (enough to comment). The question I'd like to clarify is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634624/django-html-redirects-but-doesnt-load-page); I'd like to see the poster's views.py.

Is that a situation where I should ask it in an answer, then edit/delete depending on whether I can successfully answer the poster's question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you ask a question in comments when you don't have enough reputation to do so?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252220/how-do-you-ask-a-question-in-comments-when-you-dont-have-enough-reputation-to-d) and [How should one ask for clarification on a question if they can't yet comment?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The privilege to leave comments is something that you don't gain until you reach 50 reputation points, and that's by design.  The goal is to prevent people from leaving comments until they have spent enough time to understand how the system works.

You also don't want to leave a comment as an answer. This creates more noise that the community has to clean up, and deleted answers can lead to an answer block, preventing you from posting new answers.

With that said, you're an outlier in that you understand a little better than most 8 rep users how comments work. Don't take this as a sign that you don't know what you're doing, just know that it's a barrier put in place to eliminate millions of noisy comments that would otherwise flood the system.

I just checked, and it looks like someone asked for clarification:

> [Where's your view? That's where you want to redirect. –  Dan 6 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634624/django-html-redirects-but-doesnt-load-page#comment40052612_25634624)

If someone didn't post a comment, I would have posted one on your behalf.

So just focus on answering some questions, making suggested edits, and doing the things that good users do, and in no time at all you'll surpass this barrier.  You only need about 4 or 5 more upvotes.